# warning node unrecognized graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I'm using graphviz to draw nodes

each node is identified by a long byte string like

```
J0b'\xee\x07\x9a\xbe\xd8\xa0\x8c@\nE\xc8\xcfwTT\x8a\x97\xad_\x9d\x0b\x85\x82\xb8\xe4, port 6\x0f\x17\xe1\xfbX'
```

so creating a node looks like this

```
g.node("J0b'\xee\x07\x9a\xbe\xd8\...", label="first node")
```

but then I get a warning

```
Warning: node J0b'\xee\x07\x9a\xbe\xd8\xa0\x8c@\nE\xc8\xcfwTT\x8a\
x97\xad_\x9d\x0b\x85\x82\xb8\xe4, port 6\x0f\x17\xe1\xfbX' unrecognized
```

I've been trying to find out what port is in the error online. What's weird is that only a few nodes have this error, other nodes print out correctly

So the resulting node looks like this

[image]

Instead of "first node" it prints out "J0b'\xee\x07\x9a\xbe\xd8..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [dot language grammar](http://graphviz.org/content/dot-language) states the following for node ID's:

> An *ID* is one of the following:
>
> - Any string of alphabetic ([a-zA-Z\200-\377]) characters, underscores
>     ('_') or digits ([0-9]), not beginning with a digit;
> - a numeral [-]?(.[0-9]+ | [0-9]+(.[0-9]*)? );
> - any double-quoted string ("...") possibly containing escaped quotes ('")1;
> - an HTML string (<...>).

Since the ID in your example contains also characters such as commas and spaces, the ID should be double-quoted.

For example `J0b'\xe4, port 6\x0f'` should be `"J0b'\xe4, port 6\x0f'"` (with double-quotes) when used as an id.

Furthermore, when using a library to create a graph, those id's will have to be escaped with the proper escapes sequences of the language of the library.

`g.node(""J0b'\xe4, port 6\x0f'"", "label")` should therefore probably be something like `g.node("\"J0b'\\xe4, port 6\\x0f'\"", "label")`.